# Creating a list for mobilepush

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I wanted to create a simple data extension for mobile push and was wondering how exactly does mobilepush send a push message?  What is required? For email studio it is email and SMS you need a phone

So what does mobilepush use?
According to [documenation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_into_all_contacts.htm&type=5) I need device id, system token, platform and contact key

Is device id the unique contact info for sending mobilepush? Is this device id generated atomatically from the app?

Comment: to send to a 2 a de in mobilepush you simply need the subscriberkey/contatckey

Comment: So if I create a DE with a contactkey - and I send a mobilepush to this, how will marketing cloud know to send it to my phone specifically?  There has to be some connection made no?

Comment: with the SDK you associate a deviceid to a contactkey, yo then send to that contactkey